# SIM800 HTTPS 606 Error

Tags: ssl, https, sim800

I have been using SSL to connect a SIMCOM SIM800 GSM Module to a Microsoft Azure function endpoint.  This has been working for months and has now stopped working and reports a 606 error code which indicates an "SSL alert message with a level of fatal result and the immediate termination of the connection" according to  [SIM800 Series_SSL_Application Note_V1.02](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800x/SIM800%20Series_SSL_Application%20Note_V1.02.pdf)

I tried HTTPS connections to various other sites using the SIM800 e.g. google and httpbin and got mixed results: I could connect to some e.g. google but not others e.g. httpbin.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893896/sim-800-gprs-modem-for-http-get-and-post-to-aws-iot-and-aws-api-gateway/50756276#50756276) for a similar result.

Does anyone know if sites have recently changed SSL cipher or protocol requirements? The SIM800 module (only) supports  SSL2.0, SSL3.0 and TLS1.0.

Comment: The world is indeed moving on and ditching TLS1.0 (not recommended anymore to use it) and even TLS1.1 (suggested not to run it). That leaves only TLS1.2 soon to be replaced by 1.3.

Comment: I have now found out that Azure functions can still be configured for TLS 1.0 but  they have made changes to certificates: [The current intermediate CAs used by Azure are due to expire in May 2018](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2017/04/20/azure-tls-certificates-changes/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a SIM808 (V2 / R14.18) to make some GET requests to HTTPS endpoints such a [https://www.google.com](https://www.google.es) and a personal Azure website.
I get successful answers from google but from Azure, even if change the "Minimum TLS version" I'm always having a 606 answer.
[image: Azure website's SSL Configuration]

So, I'm not sure if my SIM808 does really support TLS1.0. Maybe your SIM800 does (documentation is quite confusing).

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting a 606 error while trying to 'GET' my AWS API and I could not figure this out. Reconfigured the custom domain mapping to use TLS1.0 instead of TLS1.2 and communication is now flowing through.